# Android: Different style (textSize) for different layout sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

I have made custom style for all text buttons on large screens

```
<style name="button_large" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:soundEffectsEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Now i want smaller buttons for normal screen and I add noew style where only android:textSize changed.

```
<style name="button_normal" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:soundEffectsEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Is it posible to extract this value and recieve needed value based on screen size? And use only one style.

```
  <item name="android:textSize">value_based_on_screen_size</item>
```

And in case of large screen it weill be 30 and for normal screen it will be 10

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes that's possible. Here's how you might arrange it. In your default `values/styles.xml` have,

```
<style name="button" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/button_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:soundEffectsEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

then create a `values/dimens.xml` like this,

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="button_text_size">10sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and create a `values-large` like this,

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="button_text_size">30sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

P.s., use `sp` for fonts. it's just like `dp`, except that if the user increases the default font size through system settings, your fonts will change accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare such files first :

```
res/values-ldpi/dimens.xml
res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml
res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml
```

Then declare resource values for different files:

```
<!-- in values-ldpi/dimens.xml -->
<dimen name="mytextSize">30dp</dimen>
```

and

```
<!-- in values-mdpi/dimens.xml -->
<dimen name="mytextSize">20dp</dimen>
```

Then, use this way in your style :

```
<item name="android:textSize">@dimen/mytextSize</item>
```

Comment: screen size has no correlation to DPI. you can have xlarge screens that are mdpi (1280x800 10" tablet) or xhdpi (2560x1600 10" tablet).

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman okay thanks for the info. One que arise to me that what if I have one button and I want to specify its size for different resolutions from `dimens.xml` then what to use instead of `DPI`?

Comment: the issue is convoluted. it used to be that you'd use screen size classes: small, normal, large, and xlarge. that's deprecated in favor of size qualifiers now: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts